# How To Use setInterval in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to ask that how can i use php function again and again after some time automatically just like setInterval in Javascript. We set the time and it is on its job until the script is aborted or closed.

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<?
$Wall = new Wall_Updates();
$updatesarray=$Wall->Updates();
foreach($updatesarray as $data)
{
    $likes=$data['likes'];
    ?>
    <div id="likes"><?php echo $likes; ?></div>
    <?
}
?>
```

And Wall_Updates() Function is defined here in **FUNCTION.PHP**

```
<?php

class Wall_Updates {    
    public function Updates() {
        $myname=$_COOKIE['usename'];
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE name='$myname'");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
            $data[]=$row;
        return $data;
    }
}
?>
```

I want this Wall_Updates() function to fetch data from mysql again and again.So, It will be Updated.

Comment: You know where PHP runs and that it only generates static pages? You could use another `while` loop though, and a `sleep()` call to delay the page generation. But that's probably pointless.

Comment: It looks like you want to update your page with 'Likes' total.  You need to do this in JavaScript unless you want to reload the entire page.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For the record: I think it's bad idea. But whatever :)

Try this code

```
function setInterval($f, $milliseconds)
{
    $seconds=(int)$milliseconds/1000;
    while(true)
    {
        $f();
        sleep($seconds);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
setInterval(function(){
    echo "hi!\n";
}, 1000);
```

Or:

```
$a=1; 
$b=2;

setInterval(function() use($a, $b) {
    echo 'a='.$a.'; $b='.$b."\n";
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Why do you think it's a bad idea?

Comment: I just tried it, and my site stopped working. I used 10000 as intervall.

Comment: @b_dubb: because it behaves not like `setInterval` in javascript. Such implementation doesn't allow to do certain task "in background", when JS - does. Because JS is asynchronous, PHP - not. That is why I thought it was a bad idea.

Comment: @EdwardBlack: Because code after setInterval-call will run only __after__ setInterval finishes. Since setInterval is basicaly infinite loop - code next to it will __never__ be run. PHP is not asynchronous.

Comment: @Black It's Stopped Working because the php is not supported to Async Programming Model. It's interpreted Language.

Answer (score 12):

your solution is quite simple :

```
   $event = new EVTimer(10,2, function() {
         Do your things .. :)
   });
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ev.examples.php

Comment: This is literally the first time I've ever seen a low rep user contribute something meaningful on a years-old question. Nice! Hope to see more good answers from you in the future.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using setInterval to poll for results from a .php page using AJAx and then output your results.

So it would look something like this using jQuery:

```
<script>
    var poll = true;
    var getData = function() {
        if (poll) {
            $.get('getData.php', function(data) { $('#likes').html(data); });
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(getData, 5000);
        $('.comm').click(function() { poll = false; });
        $('.comm').blur(function() { poll = true; });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: man thats very good. I just want that, onclick of textarea with class comm (<textarea class="comm"></textarea>) this interval get clear and when the focus on textarea is no more then start interval again....Please

Comment: You can have have a variable on the page that can be used in getData to see if it get more data.  I updated the answer above to include the new variable and click/blur handlers.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Your One is Not Working But I made One By Using W3SCHOOLS.COM. The Problem I am facing is That the textarea has to be clicked twice to stop the interval. Code is Here

Comment: This is the Code: `onclick="int=window.clearInterval(int)" onblur="int=self.setInterval(function(){getData()},1000);`             This one is just in the tag of textarea and in javascript `var int=self.setInterval(function(){getData()},1000);
function getData()
{
$.get('get_post.php', function(data) { $('#display').html(data); });
}`

Comment: Your code seems to work for me, I just put it into a test page and it doesn't require clicking on the textarea twice.  Can you post your full code or give a link so I can see it?  Here's my test page: http://www.solutionsbysol.com/so.php

Comment: ok check this out: sandbox.orgfree.com and in email enter: stroam@hotmail.com and in password:myname and login then you will see a post there indicating the textarea which have to be clicked twice. ok.

Comment: see what's problem with it..Man my whole posts, likes, timeago works on load function with setinterval function which refreshes div display after 1 second. I wanted to provide a feature to user that they can comment at every post but that load function after 1 second refreshes the whole div that's why the text typed in textarea vanishes i just want solution to it.

Comment: Just tried it out, I'm getting Uncaught ReferenceError: getData is not defined and Uncaught ReferenceError: int is not defined.

Comment: hey man leave it and now check my site.....There is a link Comment on every post...check it onclick of that link interval is stopped but on textarea blur that interval is start again but if a user open the textarea and leaves it then no updates will be recieved by him..i just want that if textarea remains open for 5 seconds then hide it and start interval again....

Comment: I don't understand this code. Where is `data`defined?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what you want to achieve exactly.

Are you aware that PHP only delivers content on request?

If you want the server to update something once in a while (a file for example), use a cronjob (on *nix).

If you want your WEBPAGE to re-query something, do it in javascript and call a PHP script that delivers fresh content.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Javascript, PHP is executed on the server side. There is no setTimeout functionality in PHP. You can get close by using cronjobs - or other PHP scripts - that call your scripts though.

Comment: to achieve the functionality of an updating page, look at solcheas solution. it wasn't quite clear from the question what you wanted though ;)

Answer (score 0):

I will surgest that you use a cron job to implement such functionality in your code.
Cron will run in the background based on the instruction you give it. check out [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/introducing-cron/)

Answer (score 0):

Since the asynchronous concept of web development has to do with effecting the changes on a web page without reloading the page, we must not always run to the ways of Ajax when ever we need such effects on our web pages.

PHP can simply do the job of going to the database @ sleep seconds to retrieve some sets of data for our usage especially for chat application purposes.

See the below codes:

```
function setInterval ( $func, $seconds ) 
{
      $seconds = (int)$seconds;
      $_func = $func;
      while ( true )
      {
            $_func;
            sleep($seconds);
      }
}
```

Now, let's say we have a function `get_msg()` that goes to the database to download some sets of information. If we must do that repeatedly without the repeated usage of button calls, then, see the usage of the setInterval function written above with the `get_msg` function.

```
setInterval ( get_msg(), 5 );
```

Answer (score -1):

Javascript executes `setInterval` in other threads to continue its code-flow execution. But php hangs on the line you have called the function that is implemented by for loops.
However php supports multithreading and forking tools, but they're not recommended and not thread safety yet.