# PHP interval change

Tags: php, intervals

Here is the code. I need to change images not every refresh site but some period time ex. 1 hour. It's possible?

```
<?php
$cfg['list'] = array('s4.jpg', 's5.jpg', 's6.jpg');
$cfg['dir_images'] = 'images';

echo '<img src="'.$cfg['dir_images'].'/'.$tmp['img'].'" alt="Tekst" />';
?>


<?php
$url1=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header("Refresh: 60; URL=$url1");
?>
```

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do this, and each depends on how you want to do it, but have you tried to solve / do this yourself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Use setInterval in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783737/how-to-use-setinterval-in-php)

Comment: Yes, I try do it myself and fail everytime.

Comment: Include the code, even if it failed.

Comment: Like you sad. Example refresh auto every 60 sec. but the images also change during site refresh.

Comment: Do you need to automatically refresh your site every hour or just display a different image every hour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the time you last visited the page and the content you want to show for an hour. For example if you visit the page for the first time you save the time in a file/session/database and then check if an hour has passed.

I have made the text file version. This is for every user in the page. If you want a user specific content you would have to save the data in the session.

Other way of doing this would be with a database.

```
$folder = "pictures";

$weeds = array('.', '..'); 
$folder_files = array_diff(scandir($folder), $weeds); 

if(!file_exists('time.txt')){
    $myfile = fopen("time.txt", "w");
}

$myfile = fopen("time.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open time.txt!");
$VisitTime = fread($myfile,filesize("time.txt"));
fclose($myfile);

$PassedTime = time() - $VisitTime;
if($PassedTime > 3600){

    echo 'create new data';

    /**
    This is where the data gets saved
    Here you can create the dynamic content which will be saved in a text file.
    **/
    $random_image = array_rand($folder_files);
    $random_image = $folder_files[$random_image];
    $myfile = fopen("data.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, $random_image);
    fclose($myfile);

    $myfile = fopen("time.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, time());
    fclose($myfile);

    echo '<img src="'.$folder.'/'.$random_image.'" alt="Tekst" />';

}else{

    echo 'data already created<br/>';

    $NextDataRemake = floor(( ($VisitTime + 3600) - time()) / 60);

    echo 'Next data remake in ', $NextDataRemake, 'min.<br/>';

    $myfile = fopen("data.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $random_image = fread($myfile,filesize("data.txt"));
    fclose($myfile);

    echo '<img src="'.$folder.'/'.$random_image.'" alt="Tekst" />';
}
```

No matter how many times you refresh you will have the same images but once an hour it will be something different.

Comment: have error "data already created, next data remake..." 
and undefinied variable in line with echo.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. When that shows it means an hour has not passed and shows the same pictures

Comment: In place when img should display have text "data already created Next data remake in 41 min. Notice: Undefinied variable C:/.... on line 44 tekst" where is the last line with echo.

Comment: Oh that. It's because I just used the code you gave me and didn't implement your final idea. That you have to do yourself or you can tell me how you want the images to change after an hour. randomly or just show all the in a row changing them in an hour.

Comment: Firts sorry for my bad explain, Im new in php and learning a lot. Randomly. Finaly I want to show only one of three available in folder. But different every one hour

Comment: You code seems to be the best. Looking forward for you answer.

Comment: Okay, I will post the new code in about half an hour.

Comment: There. I edited my answer. You this takes a random picture from a folder, stores it in a file and shows for the new hour. You can have as many pictures as you want in that folder :)

Answer (score 1):

This solution will display a different image every hour.

```
//List of your images
$cfg['list'] = array('s4.jpg', 's5.jpg', 's6.jpg');
$cfg['dir_images'] = 'images';


// Get the current hour
$hour = getdate()['hours']; 

// Pick an image from the list depend on the current hour
$image_index = $hour % sizeof($cfg['list']); 

echo '<img src="'.$cfg['dir_images'].'/'.$cfg['list'][$image_index].'" alt="Tekst" />';
```

The getdate() function of php give you information about the current time.

```
array (size=11)
  'seconds' => int 24
  'minutes' => int 43
  'hours' => int 10
  'mday' => int 14
  'wday' => int 2
  'mon' => int 4
  'year' => int 2015
  'yday' => int 103
  'weekday' => string 'Tuesday' (length=7)
  'month' => string 'April' (length=5)
  0 => int 1429001004
```

Then, using `$hours % sizeof($images)` will give you a number between 0 and the number of images in your list.

Exemple:

```
9%3 = 0
10%3 = 1
11%3 = 2
12%3 = 0
```

This way, you can display a different image every hour.

Comment: Have an undefinied variable in line with echo

Comment: replace $images with $cfg['list'][$image_index]

Comment: echo '<img src="'.$cfg['dir_images'].'/'.$cfg['list'][$image_index].'" alt="Tekst" />';
change like this and now have the same error but show twice

Comment: Well, you have to include some of the code of your question, i'll update my answer.