# What does (int)10000/1000 do in php?

Tags: javascript, php, setinterval

I was looking for a setInterval method in PHP similar to the one in javascript:

```
setInterval(function() {
  /* do something amazing every ten seconds */
}, 10000);
```

and I came across this answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12783983,
whilst I was playing around with the function I realised I didn’t know what this line does:

```
$seconds=(int)$milliseconds/1000;
```

so I researched http://php.net but the closest I could find was this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

I wanted to understand what this did fully before using it on my site, so can someone please shed some light on what that line does

```
 function setInterval($f, $milliseconds) {
   $seconds=(int)$milliseconds/1000;
   while(true) {
     $f();
     sleep($seconds);
   }
 }
```

**Edit**:
after tweaking the function a bit more I came up with this:

```
function setInterval2($callBack, $seconds) {
  while(true) {
    $callBack();
    sleep($seconds/1000);
  }
}
```

Do both functions (the php versions of the functions no the javascript ones) do the same thing & get the same result?
Is there a difference between the two?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting and http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: this could be useful: http://3v4l.org/sbl48

Comment: Thank you all for the quick answer and reading material.

Comment: Note that your implementation of `setInterval()` doesn't do what the JavaScript version does. The JS one lets you set a callback when the event triggers, whereas the PHP one just prevents the script from doing anything for the specified duration.

Comment: When you say "Do both functions" and "difference between the two", are you referring to the two PHP functions you posted or the JS function and the PHP function (I'm assuming the last iteration)?

Comment: sorry for no being clear I've edited that, I meant the functions in php I wanted to know if they did the same thing as I had changed the last one a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
(int)$milliseconds/1000;
```

is basically the same as:

```
floor($milliseconds/1000);
```

The result of the division is a float value. `(int)` turns it into an integer and cuts the decimals.