# create a function with a timer php

Tags: php, timer

Hi I want to create a function with a timer that each 5 minutes calls to other function in php. Could someone help me to do this ?

Any kind of information as libraries or similar things is welcome.

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783737/how-to-use-setinterval-in-php , the accepted answer!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - Quite off topic for SO. Anyway as advise: Look for "cronjobs"

Comment: You need to create a cronejob

Comment: Is this a refresh every 5 minutes in what the client sees, or a job you need the server to do do? (What is the timer task?) This might be more a Javascript thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i tried this: 
{
$tiempo = calcTotalTime($h,$m);

do
  {
    $segactuales = microtime('true'); //devuelve los segundos que han pasado desde 1-1-1970
    $minutosactuales=(int)($segactuales/60);

```
if ($minutosactuales==$tiempo)
{
  $count++;
  echo "<br>" . $count;
}
```

}while($count<=$c);
}

but i think i need javascript because if not i get the serverd dead untill the bucle finishes

Answer (score 0):

I think that i know how to do it maybe like this

```
<?php
$time_start = microtime(true);

// Dormir por un momento
usleep(100);

$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "No se hizo nada en $time segundos\n";
?>
```

and if time is a 5 minutes multiple it will call the function. 
I'll try and now i comement