# I want to Pause / Resume Variables in PHP?

Tags: php, loops

I want to print variable `$A` and pause at that time Variable `$B`
When I print Variable `$B`,Variable `$A` already print and don't be vanish.

```
for($x=1;$x<=12;$x++){
    print_r($A);
    sleep(5);
    print_r($B);    
}
```

In this code both variable print at a same time with a wait of 5 second. But i want print $A and show to frontend and after 5 second print `$B`.

I need to perform this type of scenario in foreach() loop.

Comment: I suggest you to have a look at ajax to perform such operations

Comment: Are you trying to put these values on a web page or are you using PHP CLI?

Comment: basically i have  foreach($catProducts as $catProduct) and i want to perform this scenario in foreach that's why ajax can't make this possible

Comment: i have products and i have to show these products on wepage

Comment: Well, I don't know why you want to pause in between, but in your second `print_r()` call you also print `$A` and not `$B`.

Comment: Besides that you can't use `sleep()` in this scenario, as it will lead to delayed output of both variables. You could try to adopt sth like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783737/how-to-use-setinterval-in-php

Comment: You should be using client side javascript to do this. Not server side.

Comment: Sorry for double A,i make it correct. I will try to use your link.